# Destructuring function arguments in Clojure

Tags: clojure

I'm running an example in *Clojure Programming* by Chas Emerick et al.:

```
(defn make-user
  [& [uid]]
  {:user-id (or uid (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID)))})
```

output:

=> (make-user "T-800")

{:user-id **"T-800"**}

Now I remove the square brackets around uid in line 2:

```
(defn make-user
  [& uid]
  {:user-id (or uid (str (java.util.UUID/randomUUID)))})
```

The evaluation result becomes:

=> (make-user "T-800")

{:user-id **("T-800")**}

How to understand this difference?

Comment: Try `(make-user "T-800" :and :more :arguments)` and you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In an argument declaration, putting arguments next to `&` causes them to get wraped into a list.

```
(defn return [x y & more]
  [x y more])

(return 1 2 3 4 5 6)
;=> [1 2 (3 4 5 6)]
```

This wraping is useful to manipulate an undetermined number of args in a function:

```
(defn plus [& more] (apply + more))

(plus 3 4)
;=> 7

(plus 3 4 5 6)
;=> 18
```

But if we know there will only be one element as the optional argument and want to directly access it, we could use `first` to extract it:

```
(defn make-user-1 [& uid] {:user-id (first uid)})
(make-user-1 "T-800")
;=> {:user-id "T-800"}
```

Or, we could simply unwrap the argument element by using destructuring!

```
(defn make-user-2 [& [uid]] {:user-id uid})
(make-user-2 "T-800")
;=> {:user-id "T-800"}
```

So, here are some arg declaration and their given output:

```
(defn f [arg]     arg) ;=> arg
(defn f [& arg]   arg) ;=> (arg)
(defn f [& [arg]] arg) ;=> arg
```

The more you wrap args in the arg declaration, the more those unwrap in the body.

Answer (score 3):

[& uid]:

- `&` means putting all arguments together as a list named `uid`.
- So, `uid` here is of type list

[& [uid]]:

- putting all arguments together as `[uid]`, which is a list (not because `[]` but it is after `&`).
- In addition, do a destructuring of this list by grabbing the first element as `uid`
- So `uid` here is not a list but just one element.